# ImportXML does not return data from XML file

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, formulas

I used xpath checker to build the following xpath query:

```
/eveapi/result/rowset/row[1]/@solarSystemName
```

on the following XML document:

https://api.eveonline.com/map/Sovereignty.xml.aspx

This works in in xpath checker add on for Firefox however when i put it into a importXML query in Google sheet it does not return any data:

```
=ImportXML("https://api.eveonline.com/map/Sovereignty.xml.aspx"; "/eveapi/result/rowset/row[1]/@solarSystemName")
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: yes, the solution is to cache the target feed on your own server as the eve api feed has a delay when loading the dom which google docs doesnt like.

Comment: I just tried the IMPORTXML formula. It is working fine at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is behaving strangely as it returns immediately with a XML with currentTime element, and only after a few seconds the rest of the results are coming.

Probably the spreadsheet is not waiting for the closing tag nor to the rest of the results and returns nothing.

If you try to run

```
=ImportXML("http://api.eveonline.com/map/Sovereignty.xml.aspx", "//currentTime")
```

You will the current time of the XML as it is returning before the results.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently attribute names have to be all lower case.
This worked for me:

```
=ImportXML("https://api.eveonline.com/map/Sovereignty.xml.aspx", "//rowset/row/@solarsystemname")
```

It was pretty painful figuring that out, and let me tell you when I realized that was the issue I wanted to pull out my hair.